# Wait for API data before render react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I make two API call. Data from `getAllCampaign` api renders but for `loadStats` It appears React goes ahead to build a table without the data, thus throwing error of
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
Here's what I'm doing.

coreapihelpers:

```
export const getAllCampaign = () => {
    return fetch(`https://api.truepush.com/api/v1/listCampaign/1`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `$TOKEN`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const loadStats = async () => {
    const ids = await getAllCampaign()

    const data = Promise.all(
        ids.data.map(async (i) => await (await fetch(`https://api.truepush.com/api/v1/campaignStats/${i.campaignId}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: ``$TOKEN``,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })).json())
    )
    return data
};
```

`allData` output is delayed on console

Full code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {getAllCampaign, loadStats} from "../helpers/coreapihelpers";

const TableRow = () => {

    const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = useState([]);
    const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);

    const loadAllCampaigns = () => {
        getAllCampaign()
            .then(data => { setCampaigns(data.data) })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    };

    const loadAllStats = () => {
        loadStats()
            .then(data => { setStats(data) })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       loadAllCampaigns();
       loadAllStats();
    }, [])

    const allData = campaigns.map ? campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
        ...campaign,
        ...stats[i],
    }))
        : <h1>API LIMIT EXCEEDS</h1>

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12">
                    {allData.map ? allData.map((campaigns, index) => (
                        <div className="table-responsive" data-pattern="priority-columns">
                            <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sr. No</th>
                                    <th>Campaign Id</th>
                                    <th>Campaign Name</th>
                                    <th>Campaign Status</th>
                                    <th>Reach</th>
                                    <th>Sent</th>
                                    <th>Delivered</th>
                                    <th>Views</th>
                                    <th>Clicks</th>
                                    <th>Unsubscribers</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.campaignId}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.campaignTitle}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.campaignStatus}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Reach}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Sent}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Delivered}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Views}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Clicks}</td>
                                    <td>{campaigns.data.Unsubscribers}</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>)) : <h1>API Limit Exceeds / API Token Broken</h1>}
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            );
        }

export default TableRow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you should be checking whether state `campaigns` has been populated, not `allData`. `allData` is a variable, not the actual state. Actual state should be used for conditional rendering. Try this:

Replace this:

```
allData.map ? allData.map((campaigns, index)
```

With this:

```
campaigns ? allData.map((campaigns, index)
```

However, you should create an object for state that contains both campaigns and stats, since you intend to use them as corresponding items. Or, your database query should return them as one item with some time of join.

Try this for a client side solution:

```
const [stateObj, setObj] = useState([]);
const campaigns = [];
const stats = [];

const loadAllState = async () => {
    try {
       campaigns = await getAllCampaign();
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
    }

    try {
       stats = await loadStats();
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
    }

    setObj(campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
       ...campaign,
       ...stats[i],
  })))
};

useEffect(() => {
   loadAllState();
}, [])
```

Then:

```
stateObj ? stateObj.map((campaigns, index)
```

Comment: allData variables contains the data of campaigns as well as stats... whereas campaign state contains data of campaigns and stats contain only data of stats @silencedogood

Comment: I know that. And that's why I added the caveat at the end of my answer. You need to change the structure of your data, either by storing all data in one state object, or returning a joined data set. You can't conditionally render state with a normal variable. It must be with state. @prashantpadadune

Comment: So i should setstate the value from allData ?

Comment: @prashantpadadune Updated with possible solution.

Comment: The problem is I'm not understanding how to approach this, I'm new to programming :( also I'm not using any backend its a truepush api which I'm using to fetch my data @silencedogood

Comment: Oh i saw your update now, let me try :))) thank you :))

Comment: Dude it worked :))) you are genius thank you :)))

Comment: No problem. In a case like this (as with much in programming), there's more than one way to skin a cat. Honestly, this is not the solution I would go with overall; however, I understand that you're dealing with a pre-baked api, so this will do.

Answer (score 0):

You should see for allData if it is defined or not like this

```
 {allData ? allData.map((campaigns, index) => .......}
```

Comment: its there alldata variables contains the data of campaigns as well as stats...